# How do I make use of rotation matrices?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm confused as to how I take the values in a rotation matrix and rotate the x, y and z vertices. How do I utilize these values after I pass a D3DXMATRIX through D3DXMatrixRotationX or its respective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. You call D3DXMatrixRotationX(&output_matrix, angle) and you get a new rotation matrix stored in output_matrix. It won't rotate a matrix passed as a parameter. It will simply put a rotation matrix there. Now to add this rotation to an existing matrix you need to multiply your matrix by output_matrix. If you just want to transform a vector (vertex) by it, all you need to do is multiply this vector by output_matrix.